# How to keep your PC from locking when battery is low

Tags: windows-10, battery

My Windows 10 laptop automatically locks itself whenever its battery is low, which is EXTREMELY frustrating. The only temporary solution I've found so far is to keep it plugged in, but I'll also have to bring my PC to places without outlets eventually. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Just curious... Windows 10 is locking/going to sleep / hibernate when battery is low is to hopefully saves you from having your work lost (when the battery is completely flat) as it attempts to do a last ditch attempts to save your windows state so when the battery gone flat - your work are saved in a hibernated state (in sleep state - it will be gone). Unless you don't mind risking losing your work? But if that truly is what you want, check out Power Options in the Control Panel area. There should be some option about battery and what happens when it reach certain level.

Comment: Also just to add - making your laptop battery gone completely flat is very bad for the Li-Ion (Lithium Ion) battery. Unless your laptop is not using Li-Ion - then advice will vary. Reference: https://blog.csiro.au/power-up-our-battery-advice-free-of-charge/

Comment: Yes, I know that but computers usually give people warnings first so that they can plug the computer in before they hibernate. My computer doesn't do that; it automatically hibernates when it's battery is low.

Answer (score 1):

If you head over to Advanced Power Options and set the Sleep Time to zero then Windows will not hibernate itself and will shut the laptop off when battery is fully discharged but that will risk all unsaved data.

Comment: No, I mean like how do I make it warn me more earlier so that I can plug it in without it hibernating and staying on.

Comment: @KrystenS. Check that same location as per the answer. There should be Battery option there and you can change the Low Battery Level as you need to (so you can raise it up to 50 if you need)

Comment: I have the same question, for example if I plug in at an airport but the outlet doesn't work then Win10 won't warn you - just locks and shuts down at whatever level is set. Why not at least 1 minute ? I can't believe after so many years Windows still does such things